# How to use right shift to avoid operator division

Tags: c++, optimization, division

I have a cpp project which works but has a bad performance.

```
int currentPos = getPos();
int length = getLength();
if (1.0 * currentPos / length < 0.5)
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    // do something
}
```

The problem is: `1.0 * currentPos / length` takes too much time.

Google told me that division always took much time and we could avoid it with the help of right shift.

For example, `a=a/4` can be replaced by `b=b>>2`.

I can understand this example but I don't know how to use right shift to optimize my code as above.

If it is impossible, is there other ways to avoid division?

**EDIT**
1) The condition in `if` is not always `0.5`, it could be any rational between (0, 1).
2) The code above is executed `10 * 56 * 181 * 56 * 181` times per second.

Comment: You can do `currentPos << 1 < length` or `currentPos < length >> 1`.

Comment: You can only use shifting for integers, not floating point.

Comment: @EliSadoff   what if it is 0.7 instead of 0.5?

Comment: @Thomas Then this wouldn't work.

Comment: The equation `current / length < 0.5` is the same as `2 * current < length`. @Thomas, if the equation is `current / length < 0.7` then it will be `10 * current < 7 * length`. No division involved, only multiplication. And any multiplication by 2 can be replaced by `<< 1`.

Comment: I seriously, seriously doubt that a simple divide is causing too much time to be taken.  Have you compiled with full optimizations and also actually used a profiler to tell you where in your code that you are actually spending the most time?

Comment: For a sense of scale, on something slow like a 2GHz Core2 65nm, you could do about 60 million double precision divisions per second. On something fast like a 4GHz Skylake, about a billion per second (the difference is really that big). Either way it's a good lot of divisions before there should be a problem, so most likely there is some other trouble in the code somewhere too. If you're using a profiler, be wary of misattributions of time, it's often shifted to an innocent instruction that's waiting for the result of the slow one.

Comment: NOTE: To divide an integer by 2 you only shift by 1 ...  (4 >> 1) == 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's get honest for a moment.  On a even remotely modern CPU, division of a floating point number will be pipelined away and take roughly as much time as most other FPU or even Integer operations.

Instead, you should use a profiler on your code to see exactly where your bottlenecks are actually occurring.  As your code is written, unless it is sitting in a 1,000,000,000,000 time type for/loop, it isn't going to matter at all.

If your code IS sitting in such a loop, please let us know because there are ways of strength reducing, pre-calculating, etc. that can help in those instances outside of a simple divide hack that has been somewhat useless for a decade.

---

Update for the fact that this is indeed sitting in a 1 billion time loop.

Now then, Let's start with your two functions `GetPos()` and `GetLength()`  If you can organize your data in such a way as to make those values constant for parts of the loop, you can completely eliminate a number of memory accesses.  You can also then do the multiplication by 2 outside the loop as well.

Next, if you can organize your data such that it is sorted by length or by position before the loop is run, then you can do a binary search through your data and reduce your compares down to around a maximum of 20 or so instead of billions (the power of O(log n) vs O(n) ) and then your code goes extremely fast.

If not possible, but the data is constant per loop and the "do something" doesn't change the conditions, then this becomes embarrassingly parallel and might be able to be threaded across many CPUs - this is not as easy as it sounds though so beware.

This is just a start, but I wanted to let you see that more information allows better solutions to be offered to you.

Comment: Let's not encourage the use of division too much though, right? It still has an order of magnitude worse throughput than multiplication

Comment: Yes, it is sitting in a heavy loop. See "EDIT" part in the question.

Comment: @harold, I agree that division that is easily and naturally avoided is always a win.

Answer (score 2):

Division is avoided trivially.

```
if (length > 2 * currentPos)
```

Shift instead of division is a micro-optimisation that any decent compiler will perform automatically for you, without you messing up your code and making it unreadable.

Comment: And, most importantly, useless integer to FP conversions (and useless FP operations as well).

Comment: As a bonus this even generalizes to other rational numbers, such as the 0.7 mentioned in the comments

Comment: @Thomas: I have serious doubts that, as it is written now, this is your performance bottleneck. Use a profiler and you'll almost certainly find out that your performance problems are elsewhere.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, I'm not sure what platform Thomas is on, but I've used a microcontroller before (from the MSP430 family) that used something like 4 ms per division. With that said, I agree that profiling the code would probably point out something else as the root cause of a problem.

Comment: @Catsunami: I know that division is extremely slow on some platforms (and even on x86 even just doing all those int=>double conversions isn't free), in facts I'm referring to how the code is written by gnascher729 - this should be optimal even on extremely weak micros (it should boil down to just one arithmetic shift and a comparison).

Comment: Very minor issue - multiplying first does affect domain and can lead to integer overflow that the straight compare/division/fpu conversion code avoids.

Comment: @MatteoItalia   well, i think there is no any other way. I can be sure that the problem is just here because if I change it into `pos + 2 < length`, it has a good performance.

Comment: @Thomas - just how many times per second is the above code being called?  And what is the target system?  Those really do help us tailor our answers better.

Comment: @Thomas: that's really strange, pos*2 is normally implemented as either as a left arithmetic shift (which should take the same time as a sum or less), or summing the register with itself (which, again, should take almost the same as summing it with a constant); there must be something else going on... are you compiling with optimizations enabled? Can you provide a minimal example to test?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan   `10 * 56 * 181 * 56 * 181` times per sec

Comment: Ok, you are doing it more than a billion times per second.  That matters a bunch!  Please include that information with the question then.  And now, there are other things we can recommend.

Comment: @Thomas: my guess is that the real problem in that comparison is the branch; `pos + 2 < length` is probably always false an is well predicted by the branch predictor, while `pos * 2 < length` is much more random, so you are continuously killing the pipelines. IOW, it's not that the operation itself is any slower, is that its output in this case actually matters to the control flow. Depending from the code in the `if` you may be able to remove the branch and improve performance.

Comment: @Thomas You're right on the edge then. On a fast CPU you can hope to execute about 15 instructions per iteration and still maintain that rate, but only if it's the right mix and nothing slows it down. You'll really have to make them count. I suggest you post a more complete code in a new question, with enough context that SIMD solutions can be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way of making pretty quick divisions by a constant, but that only works if you know the value at compile-time. The general algorithm is described in the book [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/divcMore.pdf). There are plenty of examples floating around the internet as well. Your case is different, though. You retrieve length from a function

> getLength();

If however, length is not a constant, but is still the same number for several computations, you could improve performance, by computing the *reciprocal* and *multiplying* with it.

It has to do with the fact that multiplication is itself done by means of binary shifts and additions - far fewer than with division. This might be a bit tricky to implement though, as  I presume the code snippet is from within a function, so you might want to have a **global** variable (or at least external to the function, i.e. a class member).

Comment: BTW, for constants those tricks are usually implemented straight into the compilers - no need to obfuscate your code.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: To divide an integer by 2 you only shift by 1 ... (4 >> 1) == 2.
(and 4 >> 2 == 1)

---

I recently learned (the hard way) that full optimization (-O3) does not always do what you want.  (g++ v5.2.1, ubuntu 64)

In a 5x10^9 loop, I manually changed code from:

```
if (ZERO == (n & B00) // n-even
{
    ...even actions
}
else // n-odd
{
    ...odd actions
}
```

to:

```
if (n & B00) // n-odd
{
    ...odd actions
}
else // n-even
{
    ...even actions
}
```

and eliminated 8 seconds in that loop.  (to 50 from 58)

Until I tried this test, I thought the compiler a) could (and would) re-arrange the code, and b) explicitly testing for ZERO would be faster.  I was wrong.

I mention this, even though your problem appears different, because it is a remarkably SIMPLE test to try ... a few seconds of editing, followed by a compile and run.

Comment: The ==0 should be irrelevant, the point here is that you switched the branches, which should affect the initial heuristic of the branch predictor. If you know that the outcome of a branch is more likely than the other, you may use the stuff like `__builtin_expect` (maybe packaged in macros like the usual `likely` and `unlikely`) to help the compiler, or use PGO to let it figure out by itself, based on real world data.